# Humans abducted and sold as gladiators/slaves?

Tags: story-identification, alien-abduction

I'm looking for a story where a small number of humans and members of alien species are abducted by alien slavers. I believe they had canine or feline characteristics. I don't recall how it happened, maybe the slavers were betrayed by their employers, but in the end the slaves and their captors were thrown into a large arena of sorts and were being hunted. It was very Hunger-Games-esque. The humans slowly formed a kind of friendship with one of their former captors, although I believe he ended up dying. I don't remember how the story ended.

Two very specific things I remember:

- The food intended for the slaves aboard the spaceship was color-coded according to species.
- The slaver aliens follow some strange code of honor that forbids them from using ranged weaponry in personal combat. When questioned why they carried guns aboard their ship, they explained to the humans that they did not intend to use them to kill, but considered them tools for herding cattle.

Comment: I bid thirty Quatloos for the answer to this question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds to me like "**[Hunters of the Red Moon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1938185064)**", written by Marion Zimmer Bradley. If I would give a description it would include everything you have written (plus some spoilery Details).
I had to hit my Bookshelf first to make sure, since I am german and accidentally grabbed the wrong book first.