# Book - Human kidnapped by aliens and forced to fight other aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

- I read this book more than 25 years ago so it's likely 70's or earlier as it was "older" when I read it.
- It’s not long, maybe 300 pages?
- Involves human and other species
- I believe it was at least one human who was kidnapped (can't remember gender) by aliens off of a boat or some other isolated place (not a house or anything)
- Aliens pit these harvested/kidnapped species/people against each other in combat on a planet.
- It's not great writing and seemed very easy for me even at 10-12 years old.

I believe it was a female author...

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing... I just marked it as a dupe. To where I answered this before, and yet I did not remember it. :-P

Comment: Congrats on getting an answer to your question, Aridhol! Please, don't feel that your question being closed is a censure. Rather, it's how we consolidate story-id questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this *[Hunters of the Red Moon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1938185064)* by Marion Zimmer Bradley and Paul Edwin Zimmer as per [Humans abducted and sold as gladiators/slaves?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80288/humans-abducted-and-sold-as-gladiators-slaves/80358#80358)

[image: Front cover of *Hunters of the Red Moon*]

> For the Hunters, the Hunt was a religion. The Sacred Prey, sentient beings collected from all over the galaxy, were literally given a fighting chance--they were allowed to choose weapons from an armory with every imaginable weapon and given time to train. Then they were taken to the place of the Hunt, where death awaited them. Those who survived until the eclipse of the red moon, however, were honored by the Hunters and rewarded with all the wealth they could desire. The trick, of course, was surviving.

[This review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RZ2R7L24NEA2X/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=1938185064) mentions the boat abduction:

> The main character, Dane Marsh, adventurer kidnapped by aliens while sailing alone, is the kind of adventurer that Paul would create. He's a restless soul, too venturesome for the modern world and, in the course of the adventure, he is very successful with the ladies.

Found with a search for `novel human abducted "from * boat" forced to fight aliens in arena`

Comment: Wow, you found it!
Thank you so much!